# Ant-Junit integration error in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, ant, tdd

Currently I am trying to deploy my project code by using jenkins.
In this project we are using Junit to achieve TDD approach.

Now in jenkins at the end I am getting Build Failed error due to 3 errors.

1st error at junit-ant integration in xml file (i am using foundation.xml file for this purpose along with maven-structure xml file, this maven-structure xml file is importing in ant build.xml), below is my code for this integration, error showing at 1st line only (Test Failed: error in jenkins console):

```
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${test.haltonfailure}"    haltonerror="${test.haltonerror}" fork="true" forkmode="perBatch" dir="${basedir}">
                <jvmarg value="-Xms256m"/>
                <jvmarg value="-Xmx600m"/>
                <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=600m"/>
                <jvmarg value="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"/>
                <jvmarg value="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"/>
                <sysproperty key="COMPUTERNAME" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}"/>
                <sysproperty key="messaging.properties" value="${messaging.properties}"/>
                <sysproperty key="log.dir" value="${build.testoutput}"/>
                <sysproperty key="messaging.dir" value="."/>
                <sysproperty key="log4j.debug" value="true"/>
                <sysproperty key="aib.tests.selector.productMetaData" value="${pmf.testSelectorValue}"/>
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="test.execution.classpath"/>
                    <path refid="test.config.path"/>
                </classpath>
                <formatter type="xml"/>
                <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${build.testoutput}">
                    <fileset refid="test.classesToTest.fileset"/>
                </batchtest>
                <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${build.testoutput}" if="test.classesToTestInSeperateJVM.fileset.nonempty">
                    <fileset refid="test.classesToTestInSeperateJVM.fileset"/>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
```

2nd error The following error occurred while executing this line:
is in build.xml  **

> param name "include.pmf.tests" line

**

```
<target name="ci-build" description="runs the ci version of the build process">
    <antcall target="base-build">
        <param name="include.pmf.tests" value="true"/>
        <param name="analyse.code" value="false"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

and last erroris The following error occurred while executing this line:
also in build.xml, while building one of the module(SDK)

```
    <build dir="business-domain"/>
```

after successful build i want to generate Junit-report for various test-suits. Junit test-report xmls are generating right now for each module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot the following code

```
<junitreport todir="${build.testoutput}/test">
                   <fileset dir="${build.testoutput}">
                       <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
                   <report todir="${build.testoutput}/test/reports"/>
         </junitreport>
```

which causing the issue. configuration error while publishing the junit report.